# If my Android app is running in 'Unrestricted' battery mode, will its background services still terminated?

Tags: android, android-service

In [this article](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background) on Android background execution limits, it states that background services will be killed off after a period of time, once the app is idle. It does not give any exceptions to this.

In an a specific apps battery settings, you can put the app into "Unrestricted mode", which explicitly states "Allow this app to use battery in the background without restrictions".

The article on Android background execution limits gives no mention of Unrestricted battery mode...which seems like an oversight and contradiction. It gives no exceptions to the rules, but at the same time, the unrestricted setting clearly states that it removes ALL restrictions.

Comment: The restriction on background services is not purely tied to the battery, and AFAIK it is not affected by that battery usage setting on newer Android versions.

Comment: More of an FYI as OEM battery restrictions differ, see: https://dontkillmyapp.com/